# SSRS - Dynamics 365 - Invoices Per account

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Hello I want to create SSRS report showing invoices per customer the customer could have a parent account
I created a table grouped by parent account and 2 different datasets one for the first column and one for the second , for second column values are summed wrong since it is populated from different dataset

[image]

How could I use different datasets populating correct numbers

Comment: I don't think you would need two datasets to accomplish this.

Comment: But I have different conditions for each column